# Taglib Qt read access violation

Tags: qt, taglib

It seems like when you try to get the rating from an mp3 in taglib and its been opened it will cause a read access violation:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
QFile fileInfo(file);
fileInfo.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
if(fileInfo.isReadable())
{
    TagLib::MPEG::File mpeg(file.toStdString().c_str());
    bool isRead = mpeg.isReadable(file.toStdString().c_str());
    if(isRead)
        rating = dynamic_cast<TagLib::ID3v2::PopularimeterFrame *>(mpeg.ID3v2Tag()->frameList("POPM").front())->rating();
}
```

I've tried adding a try/catch but it still fails.  I have tried QLockFile with no success. Is there any way to test if a file has exclusive rights to a file or catch the read access violation?

**Update**
Thanks to the tip I modified my code to check for invalid values first:

```
if(mpeg.ID3v2Tag() != 0)
{
    if(dynamic_cast<TagLib::ID3v2::PopularimeterFrame *>(mpeg.ID3v2Tag()->frameList("POPM").front()) != 0)
    {
        rating = dynamic_cast<TagLib::ID3v2::PopularimeterFrame *>(mpeg.ID3v2Tag()->frameList("POPM").front())->rating();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read access violation has nothing to do with file read, you program tries to do a read-access of memory it can't access.

In your case you are trying to access a null pointer (`0x0`).

You have two pointer access operations in your last line of code, cehck both for not being a null pointer before trying to call methods on them

Comment: What is a good way to split this up.  When I first try TagLib::ID3v2::Tag *id3v2 = mpeg.ID3v2Tag();  I get id3v2 is undeclared identifier

Comment: Strange, that looks valid to me if `Tag` is a valid type in namespace `TagLib::ID3v2`

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting this problem because of the code you had in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477563/taglib-adding-a-tag-that-doesnt-exist/42003593#42003593).  You're creating a `POPM` frame the wrong way, and then the cast is failing.

**Note**: `dynamic_cast` is a checked cast type.  It returns zero when it fails, as it is here.  You need to check the return value before assuming it works (otherwise you would generally use a `static_cast`).