# Taglib adding a tag that doesnt exist

Tags: c++, taglib

I'm adding a frame that doesnt exist to some of my mp3.  Example the rating "POPM" is missing.  The problem I have is when I add the frame I cant set the ratings value. I have two save() there that I used one at a time just to see if either one worked.  But if I re-run this function and isPOPMExist is now valid I can set the rating.  So i'm not sure what step is missing after i set the POPM when isPOPMExist fails

```
bool isPOPMExist = id3v2Tag->frameListMap().contains("POPM");
if(!isPOPMExist)
{
    TagLib::ByteVector bytePOPM("POPM");

    TagLib::ID3v2::TextIdentificationFrame *frame = new TagLib::ID3v2::TextIdentificationFrame(bytePOPM, TagLib::String::UTF8);
    id3v2Tag->addFrame(frame);
    // frame->setText("");
    file.save();
    dynamic_cast<TagLib::ID3v2::PopularimeterFrame *>(file.ID3v2Tag()->frameList("POPM").front())->setRating(255);
    file.save();
}   
else
{
   auto framelistCount = file.ID3v2Tag()->frameList("POPM").size();
   if(framelistCount > 0)
   {
       if(dynamic_cast<TagLib::ID3v2::PopularimeterFrame *>(file.ID3v2Tag()->frameList("POPM").front()) != 0)
       {
           int ratingVal = (int)rating;
           dynamic_cast<TagLib::ID3v2::PopularimeterFrame *>(file.ID3v2Tag()->frameList("POPM").front())->setRating((int)rating);

           return file.save();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't `dynamic_cast` between `ID3v2::TextIdentificationFrame` and `ID3v2::PopularimeterFrame`.  They're unrelated frame types, so the cast will always fail.  You need to create the `ID3v2::PopularimeterFrame` directly with `new`, e.g.:

```
auto frame = new TagLib::ID3v2::PopularimeterFrame;
frame->setRating(1);
tag->addFrame(frame);
file.save();
```